# Is displaying the directory allowed in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file, upload

I am doing a system in which the staff is allowed to upload files to let the students view/download it. I have managed to display the content (all files) of that specific module on the page and the user can view or download it but I am just wondering whether or not it is possible to allow the staff to create a folder and upload a file in there and then manage that folder for example delete that folder and go inside that folder and delete chosen file in that particular folder.

So something like a file manager on the web page. I am trying to implement a basic blackboard type system.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mkdir( $pathname )` method in PHP  to create directorys.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

In terms of file uploading, I created a simple to use PHP class which you can use to upload images:

https://github.com/tehlulz/PHP-Upload

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
I have already done making a unique directory for the module from its name and then uploading any file in that folder using the class. All I need now is extend the functionality to allow the teachers to create a sub folder and upload the file in there if they wish.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I could go about it:

1. Create a table which will store which directories staff have permissions
2. On a control panel, show all directories they are allowed, with a WHERE clause
3. Let them do stuff...delete, edit etc